# Error de Formato de Fecha - Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angular

Usando angular material tengo un selector de fecha que al escoger una determinada fecha, lo que me muestra es un formato completado con ceros que es la zona horaria ("2021-01-28T05:00:00.000Z").

El problema es que es un componente hijo con un formControl y quisiera formatear la fecha para que solo me muestre el año mes y día (2020-12-31), alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Aqui esta el ejemplo en stackblitz: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-homnw8?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

te invito a utilizar [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/docs/).

Para insertarlo directamente en la página, mira este [enlace](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/browser/). Una prueba rápida:

```js
console.log("Fecha",moment());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Ahora, vamos a [*parsear*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) lo anterior:

```js
console.log("Fecha",moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una cosa es rcopilar los datos y otra mostrar, como guardas una fecha importa solo cuando se trata de zonas horarias, lo de más como quieres.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]